# Qt: Get a standard cursor pixmap

Tags: c++, qt, qpixmap, qcursor

The `QCursor` class provides methods get and set a `QPixmap` or a `QBitmap` on the cursor. I can create a cursor from one of the standard shapes, e.g. `Qt::ArrowCursor`. However, if I do so, I cannot get the pixmap/bitmap of the cursor!

```
QCursor cursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);
qDebug() << cursor.pixmap().isNull()
         << cursor.bitmap()
         << cursor.mask();
```

Will generate the output

```
true 0x00 0x00
```

I know the documentation says it's not possible, but I need to get the pixmap/icon/image/animation/whatever of a specific cursor.

So, is there a way to get the icon of a standard cursor from Qt? I'm wondering because if you drag an item from a `QListView`, it will show both, the standard cursor an the image of whatever I am dragging!

Comment: According to the documentation, this is not possible

Comment: A standard cursor doesn't necessarily *have* a pixmap. It may be animated, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Plain and simple, you can't.

> `QPixmap QCursor::pixmap() const`
>
> Returns the cursor pixmap. This is only valid if the cursor is a pixmap cursor.

The reason is that for builtin cursors Qt just asks the operating system to use that particular shape by means of symbolic constants, without ever accessing the actual pixmap.

Comment: I know that much - but can I get the pixmap?

Comment: Not by using Qt APIs. I have no idea about the platform specific ones.